# pySpark Processing a tuple of strings. zipWithIndex 'tuple' object has no attribute 'zipWithIndex'

Tags: python, apache-spark, tuples, pyspark, dna-sequence

I have created a complex data structure:

> [(u'AGGCGTATGAAGACGTGCTG', ((u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG',
>   u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAGA', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG',
>   u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG'),
>   (u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA', u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA',
>   u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA', u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA',
>   u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA')))]

The first element is a barcode.  The second is a tuple with two tuples inside. Both of these tuples contain 1-n sequences.  I want to do a calculation over each tuple to find the consensus sequence.  When I try to do [zipWithIndex](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=zipwithindex#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex) though, I get an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'zipWithIndex'.

I've been trying to work through getting the tuple with the sequences into its own RDD, but it seems like the only way I can get those to be able to processed with a map is to use sc.parallelize(tuple) and that doesn't work within a map (because Spark doesn't support nested calculations).

My goal is to create a consensus sequence of each of the lists of sequences in the tuple.  ie:

> (u'AGGCGTATGAAGACGTGCTG', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG',
>   u'AACAGTTTCTGGAGTTATTA').

The approach I was planning on using is to use zipWithIndex to create a (0,'T'), (1,'A'), (2,'G')... list that I could use a groupByKey to calculate the consensus, similar to [here](https://github.com/mcapuccini/spark-tutorial/blob/master/spark-tutorial/src/main/scala/se/uu/farmbio/tutorial/Consensus.scala).

Pyspark code:

```
 dnaArray = dnaRDD.map(lambda line: line.split('\t'))
 reads = dnaArray.map(lambda x: (x[4],x)).map(lambda x: (x[0], [x[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
 def sortBarcodes(l,r,s1,s2):
   if l > r:
     return (l+r,'ab',[s1,s2])
   else:
     return (r+l, 'ba', [s2, s1])

 # sort the barcode and then return the sequences in the proper order
 readBarcodes = reads.map(lambda x: (x[0], sortBarcodes(x[1][0][0],x[1][1][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1][1])))
 barcodeGroups = readBarcodes.map(lambda x: (x[1][0],x[1][2]))
 import collections
 def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

  def buildSeqs(x,y):
    # concatenate all of inner 0 and all of inner 1
    n = tuple(flatten((x[0], y[0])))
    m = tuple(flatten((x[1], y[1])))
    return(n,m)

   seqs = barcodeGroups.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: buildSeqs(x,y))
   # here's where I'd like to do a seqs.map(lambda seq: seq[1][0].zipWithIndex()....)

   # test code
   t = seqs.map(lambda x: x[1][0])
   t.take(1)
   [(u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAGA', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG', u'TAGCATGGAATTTGAAATAG')]
   s = t.map(lambda x: x.zipWithIndex().map(lambda res,pos: (res,pos)))
   s.take(1)
   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'zipWithIndex'
```

Comment: `tuple.zipWithIndex()`? Did you mean `enumerate`?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=zipwithindex#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex

Comment: Are you sure you *have* a `RDD`? Because the error message says that you don't.

Comment: I don't have an RDD, but I'm not sure how to convert my tuple (or list) into one.  The outer object (seqs) is a RDD (PythonRDD[763] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48).

Comment: It is rather unlikely you want to convert tuple into RDD (unless of course you put a whole something like results of a WGS there). Use `enumerate` as proposed by @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.

Comment: This is the results of an NGS run.  There should be around 1000 sequences in each of the lists of sequences and there are typically around 500,000 sequences.

Comment: You still don't want RDD (or even cannot use one) there. You probablly want something like this `t.flatMap(lambda xs: (enumerate(x) for x in xs)).flatMap(lambda x: x)`. And forget about `groupByKey` here.

Comment: Or `t.map(lambda xs: Counter(chain(*(enumerate(x) for x in xs))))` if you want to operate per sequence (`chain` and `Counter` from `itertools` and `collections`  respectively)